# Oracle SQL showing matching data from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Hi I have following table:

```
Id  Code  Acct
=================
1   002   123456
1   004   123456
2   004   456789
2   004   123456
3   001   3456456
4   005   975236
5   006   146387
6   004   0054321
6   010   123456
7   008   165432
7   007   987654
7   002   123456
```

and I need to find the ids that have matching `Code` and `Acct`, in the following way:

```
Code Acct    Id1 Id2
=====================
002  123456  1   7
004  123456  1   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select code, account, min(id), max(id)
from t
group by code, account
having count(*) > 1;
```

Note:  This only returns two example ids that match.  If you want all of them, you can use `listagg()`:

```
select code, account, listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids
from t
group by code, account
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Self-join (lines #1 - 15 represent sample data; query you need begins at line #16):

```
SQL> with test (id, code, acct) as
  2    (select
  3  1,   '002',   123456  from dual union all select
  4  1,   '004',   123456  from dual union all select
  5  2,   '004',   456789  from dual union all select
  6  2,   '004',   123456  from dual union all select
  7  3,   '001',   3456456 from dual union all select
  8  4,   '005',   975236  from dual union all select
  9  5,   '006',   146387  from dual union all select
 10  6,   '004',   0054321 from dual union all select
 11  6,   '010',   123456  from dual union all select
 12  7,   '008',   165432  from dual union all select
 13  7,   '007',   987654  from dual union all select
 14  7,   '002',   123456  from dual
 15  )
 16  select a.code, a.acct, a.id id1, b.id id2
 17  from test a join test b on a.code = b.code
 18                         and a.acct = b.acct
 19                         and a.id > b.id
 20  order by code, acct;

COD       ACCT        ID1        ID2
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
002     123456          7          1
004     123456          2          1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, nevertheless, I have a huge table and just showed a part of it, so how to deal with large table because making the WITH will be virtually impossible.

Comment: The WITH factoring clause is just a simple way to create sample data when you want to show how something works. You already have data in your tables. Code you might be interested in begins at line #16.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an arbitrary number of duplicates (ie, more than 2 is possible), or you want a single pass through the table, you can use some analytic SQL

```
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3  select 1 id,  002 code, 123456 acct from dual union all
  4  select 1,  004 , 123456 acct from dual union all
  5  select 2,  004 , 456789 acct from dual union all
  6  select 2,  004 , 123456 acct from dual union all
  7  select 3,  001 , 3456456 acct from dual union all
  8  select 4,  005 , 975236 acct from dual union all
  9  select 5,  006 , 146387 acct from dual union all
 10  select 6,  004 , 0054321 acct from dual union all
 11  select 6,  010 , 123456 acct from dual union all
 12  select 7,  008 , 165432 acct from dual union all
 13  select 7,  007 , 987654 acct from dual union all
 14  select 7,  002 , 123456 acct from dual
 15  ),
 16  dups as (
 17   select t.*,
 18      count(*) over ( partition by code,acct ) as dup_cnt
 19    from t
 20  )
 21  select code, acct, listagg(id,',') within group ( order by id) as id_list
 22  from dups
 23  where dup_cnt > 1
 24  group by  code, acct;

      CODE       ACCT ID_LIST
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         2     123456 1,7
         4     123456 1,2
```

Comment: You can remove the dups subquery completely and simply use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much and yes I do have more than two matches. The only issue is my table is pretty large and just showed a part  of it. So, how to create WITH clause for a large table.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `LISTAGG` then `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

```
SELECT CODE,
       ACCT,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (CONCT,
                      '[^,]+',
                      1,
                      1)
          ID1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (CONCT,
                      '[^,]+',
                      1,
                      2)
          AS ID2
  FROM (WITH MAIN
             AS (SELECT 1 AS ID, '002' AS CODE, '123456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 AS ID, '004' AS CODE, '123456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 AS ID, '004' AS CODE, '456789' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 AS ID, '004' AS CODE, '123456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3 AS ID, '001' AS CODE, '3456456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 4 AS ID, '005' AS CODE, '975236' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 5 AS ID, '006' AS CODE, '146387' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 6 AS ID, '004' AS CODE, '0054321' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 6 AS ID, '010' AS CODE, '123456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 7 AS ID, '008' AS CODE, '165432' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 7 AS ID, '007' AS CODE, '987654' AS ACCT FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 7 AS ID, '002' AS CODE, '123456' AS ACCT FROM DUAL)
          SELECT A.CODE,
                 A.ACCT,
                 LISTAGG (A.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ID) AS CONCT
            FROM MAIN A
        GROUP BY A.CODE, A.ACCT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df745/18)

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE (CODE, ACCT) IN (
SELECT CODE, ACCT FROM (
select count(1), CODE, ACCT FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY CODE, ACCT HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) T))
SELECT X.ID ID1, Y.ID ID2, X.CODE, X.ACCT FROM CTE1 X, CTE1 Y WHERE X.CODE = Y.CODE AND X.ACCT
= Y.ACCT AND X.ID > Y.ID;
```